# Django - passing data from a python script to a django view

Tags: python, django

I have a python script with my django models imported to it, it does a little data treatment to the objects and I get some values for example a dictionary called travel and two lists: city and route;

My script runs in a view:

```
class UpdateObject(UpdateView):
    [...]
    command = "python script.py"
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    [...]
```

I would like to pass the variables with the values that I got with the script to another view

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    [...]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to split `script.py` into two parts:

- a module that exposes a function that does something with model instances
- a command that imports that module and runs the function with command-line arguments

Then you can just import the function both from the view and from the command-line script. A function call sounds more convenient and efficient compared to spawning a separate python process and passing all parameters through command line.